# Submit new version of app using XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

I have an existing app live with version 1.0

Now I want to submit a new version (say 1.1). Using XCode 4, what are the steps to submit the same ?

Can I update the screenshots as well ?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: They have pretty solid walkthroughs on the developer site. Have you tried going to the Connect site? Is there a particular step you're having a problem with?

Comment: I have never added a new app version...
Where exactly can I find the steps , specifically for a new version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Clean your target
2. Go to the **Build Settings** and find **Code Signing Identity** field.
3. Change *Release* identity to your *iOS Distribution*
   [image]
4. **Build > Archive** your target. Organizer should pop-up.
5. Click Validate/Submit.

You can't, however, upload screenshots via Xcode4. It must be done in iTC.

Comment: Thx a lot...When you say "Change Release identity to your iOS Distribution"....what exactly do I need to put...I already have some value from my version 1.0...SO do I need to change that ?

Also in ITC, what all do I need to update ?

Comment: @Hashiv : the only things you need to update in ITC are the screenshots (if needed) and the apps description

Comment: @testndtv I attached a screenshot to my answer

Comment: Well my only question is, since there is already a version 1.0 which is live, I already have the Release identity set....Just wanted to understand the things specific for adding a new version v1.1

Comment: You only have to change **Bumdle Version** field in your **Info.plist** and add a version placeholder in iTC.

Comment: Yeh...that is exactly what i was looking for....